# Does anyone know what this is and how to remove it?

Tags: drywall

This is the object in my friend’s apartment. It looks like a command hook and nails but was put up by previous tenant. We need to know what it is to be able to remove it. [image: it is like a command hook with nails]

Comment: it's a picture hook ... ask the landlord to remove it

Answer (score 0):

As @jsotola said, it's a picture hook. It'd held in place with the four small nails you see. If you want to get rid of it, you should be able to pull straight outward from the wall to extract them; you may need pliers to get a good enough grip.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, it's a picture hook.
You may be able to ease it out with just two blunt dinner/butter knives, slid in from opposite sides simultaneously. They don't usually take much effort to remove, but gentle pressure from a large, flat, blunt blade might be best to avoid any damage to the wall.

[image]